# Group by two columns and adding a column with new 'indexing'

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to group a dataframe by two columns (b and c) and have a third column (a) with a number (or new indexing) for unique values in b and c.

For example:

```
         b         c         d         e
1        1         3       7.5       3.4
2        1         3       4.6       5.5
3        4         2       5.5       4.3
4        5         1       3.2       9.1
5        4         2       6.4       9.2
```

This is the desired output:

```
         a         b         c         d         e
1        1         1         3       7.5       3.4
2        1         1         3       4.6       5.5
3        2         4         2       5.5       4.3
4        3         5         1       3.2       9.1
5        2         4         2       6.4       9.2
```

Comment: Use `df['a'] = df.groupby(['b','c']).ngroup() + 1`